# get user input when i run python program through pythonw.exe

Tags: python, cmd

How can i run python programm as background process and show cmd for input and output operation only.
consider the following code:

```
import pyttsx3;
import pickle;
import speech_recognition as sr
engine = pyttsx3.init();
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate-25)
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume', volume+0.50)
mic_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x825: Audio (hw:1, 0)"
sample_rate = 8000
chunk_size = 128
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic_list = sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
engine.say(" Hello Mr.amit  , welcome to the first project");
engine.runAndWait();
engine.say("please enter username and password ");
engine.runAndWait();
 print("please enter username and password")
 c=input("Username:")
d=input("Password:")
ss=0
pickle_in = open("dictpersonal.pickle","rb")
users= pickle.load(pickle_in)
for us in users:
  if(c==us):
     engine.say("log in successfully");
     engine.runAndWait();
     print("log in successfully as =",c);
     ss=ss+1;
     break;
if(ss==0):
    engine.say("Username not found.Want to sign up using this username,enter y ");
```

all i want is to open cmd only when an input or output operation is required.if i use pythonw.exe to run this program

```
pythonw.exe C:\Users\amit\Desktop\MachineLearning\Projects\Personal\f3.py
```

i can not insert username and password

Answer (score 0):

By using `pythonw.exe`, this whole python process will not be able to use the terminal.

You may try to use a GUI library, such as [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: can u resolve this issue also   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053103/how-to-add-ynbox-and-messagebox-in-same-window-using-easygui