# How to add ynbox and messagebox in same window using easygui

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I run following code :

```
import easygui
easygui.ynbox('Shall I continue?', 'Title', ('Yes', 'No'))
easygui.msgbox('This is a basic message box.', 'Title Goes Here');
```

but i get different window for ynbox and msgbox ,i want bot  both of them to be included in same window

Answer (score 0):

Just do single `ynbox`:

```
import easygui
easygui.ynbox('Question', 'Title', ('Yes', 'No'))
```

Or do `buttonbox`:

```
import os
easygui.buttonbox('Message', 'Title', choices=(['Button[1]', 'Button[2]' , 'Button[3]']))
```